# How to receive publishTime

Tags: go, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, publish-subscribe

I have a GC function in Go, It is triggered by pubsub push subscription to a topic. I am trying to receive the publishTime and it does not appear populated.

The specs say string (Timestamp format), however, that field in my model is empty. Every other piece of information is populated except publishTime.

```golang
type PubSubMessageModel struct {
    Data        []byte            `json:"data"`
    Attributes  map[string]string `json:"attributes"`
    PublishTime string            `json:"publishTime"`
}
```

Simply trying to log the property;

```golang
log.Info().Msgf("Publish Time is - %s\n", m.PublishTime)
```

results in an empty string:

`Publish Time is -`

Any suggestions?

Comment: Could you please update your question and add parts of your code that publish and listen for messages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not very well documented, but it is.

The [event structure is different](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/calling/pubsub#event_structure) when you have a push to the function directly compare to a push Subscription with a HTTP triggered function.

> Instead, you can access publishTime and messageId via the event ID and timestamp properties of the event metadata. This metadata is accessible via the context object that is passed to your function when it is invoked.

In the [background context description](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/writing/background#function_parameters), in Go, there is an explanation of the package to use (functions/metadata) to get the context values

---

Here how to achieve this

1. Perform a `go get cloud.google.com/go`
2. Use this dependency in your code and get the message metadata from the context

```
import (
    "cloud.google.com/go/functions/metadata"
    "context"
    "log"
)

type PubSubMessage struct {
    Data []byte `json:"data"`
}

// HelloPubSub consumes a Pub/Sub message.
func HelloPubSub(ctx context.Context, m PubSubMessage) error {
    meta,err := metadata.FromContext(ctx)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
        return err
    }
    log.Printf("publishTime, %s", meta.Timestamp)
    log.Printf("messageId, %s", meta.EventID)
    log.Printf("Type, %s", meta.EventType)
    log.Printf("Resource, %s", meta.Resource)
    return nil
}
```